# port 3389 won't open up on azure vm

Tags: azure, rdp

when i try to do rdp, it doesn't work.

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep rdp

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      106888/xrdp-sesman
```

1. The above command is supposed to return one more line having port 3389 as open, but it doesn't.
2. In the NSG, i have opened inbound connections on port 3389, and in a connection test in the azure console, it shows that inbound connections to the port is working.

This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What is your OS image?

Comment: The image is of Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you created a Windows/Linux VM from Market Place image, so by default 3389 is allowed inside Windows Firewall, for Linux this port 3389 might be your service running on this port. When you create a NSG rule form traffic outside, you must use private IP of your VM.

You need to make sure that your NSG is associated either to your NIC or SUBNET of VM, so I suggest you to test it using Network Watcher, use the same Remote IP address 200.200.200.200 and port 45654, it is up to you, it must has a public IP and a port from the source. For local IP address and port you put information about your VM (private IP). In my case it is not allowed port 3389.

[image: network watcher]

Another test you can do, in case that you have another VM in the same SUBNET of this one, try to telnet PRIVATE_IP 3389.

Comment: IP flow verify says Access Allowed. I am using a Linux VM. Why would the xrdp not be listening in Port 3389?(seen from "sudo netstat -plnt | grep rdp" in my question)

Comment: Are you trying to access this Linux from outside (internet) on port 3389? Or are you complaining that xrdp service is not working as expected? According to your test (network watcher) it proves that traffic from outside to your Linux VM has no rule which is blocking it, so I suggest you to focus on how to fix xrdp service, I mean to make it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more thing, when I do "nmap" from my pc, it shows that the port is "closed". Could it be "closed" due to the xrdp service not working, rather than the firewall(NSG) blocking it?

Comment: Most likely you are having an issue inside your Linux VM. You can test another port, for example, does it have SSH enabled? Try to do a telnet on port 22 (make sure NSG has rule for port 22). Another test, from console of this VM, try a telnet YOUR_IP 3389. Focus on test inside your VM, jusst in case check iptables if it has. If you familiar with tcpdump, so you can start a tcpdump inside your VM and check incoming packets from your source. I can help about Azure, network, but xrdp service, I don't know how it works.